Problems Connecting Facebook Pages in My App
a few months ago I requested the corresponding permissions in my app V.18.0: pages_messaging, public_profile, pages_manage_metadata, pages_read_engagement, pages_show_list, and business_management. All permissions were granted. However, when trying to make the connection, no pages appeared for me to connect to; it showed 'list is empty'. So, I updated my app to V.20.0. Now, if there is one page, I can establish the connection, but if there are 2 or more pages, it still shows as 'list is empty'. Do you have any advice on how to solve this? I've checked permissions settings for the pages and the app, but I can't identify the issue.
I expected all the Facebook pages I have to appear in my app so that I could select one or all of them and receive their Messenger messages in my application. I tried upgrading from version 18.0 to version 20.0, but it still doesn't work.
